# ActivityBuilder.Implementation doesn't include NamespacesForImplementation when serialized

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm having a problem serializing to xaml a `WorkflowService` that includes an `ActivityBuilder` for its `Body` parameter. The `ActivityBuilder` contains C# expressions and the serialized `WorkflowService` doesn't activate because some C# expressions refer to custom types. The actual error is "Type 'SomeTypeIPassToAnArgument' is not defined".

My `ActivityBuilder` is created from a xaml file which includes a `TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation` element. This is missing when the `WorkflowService` is serialized and it seems this is the cause of the problem.

I found that if I serialize the `ActivityBuilder` itself, the namespaces are included, but using `ActivityBuilder.Implementation` fails. Unfortunately, when I build the `WorkflowService` to serialize I have to use `ActivityBuilder.Implementation` as its `Body` parameter. I tried using the `TextExpression.SetNamespacesForImplementation` method to ensure these were attached to the implementation but that didn't help.

The following snippet shows what I'm trying to do and where it's failing.

```cs
var loadedXaml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\workflow.xaml");
Assert.IsTrue(loadedXaml.Contains("NamespacesForImplementation"));

var xamlReader = new XamlXmlReader(new StringReader(loadedXaml));
var builderReader = ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderReader(xamlReader);
var builder = XamlServices.Load(builderReader) as ActivityBuilder;

// namespaces are available in the builder itself
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, TextExpression.GetNamespacesForImplementation(builder).Count);

// when saving, the assert fails because the namespaces aren't serialized
var savedXaml = XamlServices.Save(builder.Implementation);
Assert.IsTrue(savedXaml.Contains("NamespacesForImplementation"));
```

Any idea why this isn't working, or if there's an alternative approach I could use that would work? Ultimately my aim is to be able to load workflows from xaml and incorporate them in a serialized `WorkflowService` that I can host in an MVC app using a `VirtualPathProvider`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use ActivityBuilder as the body of a WorkflowService, ActivityBuilder is just intended to manipulate an Activity at design time. To convert your ActivityBuilder to an Activity, use ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter.

You can leverage XamlServices.Transform to pipe a XamlReader over your ActivityBuilder to the writer you create in ActivityXamlServices.CreateBuilderWriter.